# Double records on list.getItems using Javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin, csom

Using fairly straight forward code to get back a country list for the user...but each time it loads I'm getting double items...i.e all the items are in the drop down twice...in fact time I trigger the function it keeps adding to the list...anyone had this?

```
/ This function will populate the drop down menu for countries
function getCountryddl() {
$('#cboCountry').empty();
var cboCountries = document.getElementById("cboCountry");
cboCountryList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('CountriesLimits');
var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
var cboCountryListItems = cboCountryList.getItems(camlQuery);
context.load(cboCountryListItems);
context.executeQueryAsync(
   function () {
       // Success returned from executeQueryAsync
       if (cboCountryListItems.get_count() > 0) {

           var cboCountryListItemEnumerator1 = cboCountryListItems.getEnumerator();
           // Lets add the please select option
           var pleaseSelect = document.createElement("option");
           pleaseSelect.innerHTML = "Please Select";
           pleaseSelect.value = "";
           cboCountries.insertBefore(pleaseSelect);
           // Check if this is a gift or entertainment
           var cboGorE = document.getElementById("cboGorE");
           var cboGorEselectedValue = cboGorE.options[cboGorE.selectedIndex].value;

           // Lets get the select items
           while (cboCountryListItemEnumerator1.moveNext()) {
               var cboCountryListItem1 = cboCountryListItemEnumerator1.get_current();
               var country = cboCountryListItem1.get_fieldValues()["Title"];
               var id = cboCountryListItem1.get_fieldValues()["Title"];

               if (cboGorEselectedValue == "Gift") {
                   var Limit = cboCountryListItem1.get_fieldValues()["GiftLimit"];
               }
               else { var Limit = cboCountryListItem1.get_fieldValues()["HospitalityLimit"]; }
               var option = document.createElement('option');
               option.innerHTML = country;
               option.value = Limit + "-" + country;
               cboCountries.appendChild(option);

           }
           //Countries are loaded
           $('#countryLoading').hide();
           $('#countryLoaded').show();

       }
       else { alert("There are no Countries setup. Add some now"); }
   },
   function (sender, args) {
       // Failure returned from executeQueryAsync
       alert("Error in Populating Business Units: " + args.get_message());
   }



   );

}
```

Comment: Upon further investigation it would seem my list is deploying the data twice?! weird.

Comment: Turns out it was the lists that were corrupted. They were created before i had added the "Office 365" development tools to my visual studio. Recreated the lists and problem has gone.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted seems ok. The problem is that this code is getting called multiple times.

**The quick and easy solution**

The simple solution is to move your `$('#cboCountry').empty();` line into your success callback rather than at the top of your function. This will clear out the select immediately before repopulating it. Your function is asynchronous.  If you call it twice in succession the two callbacks will execute some time after the two main function bodies have executed.  That's why your control is getting double-populated.

**The "correct" solution**

It seems weird that your function is getting called multiple times.  Maybe there is a good reason for that, but if there isn't you should get to the bottom of that and fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I have used that method but it did not help. Read my comment above for the solution